# can someone explain this one hot encoding command

Tags: python

I am going to be using one hot encoding to change a categorical feature to a numerical feature, the NSL-KDD dataset will be getting used. I came across this bit of code someone has used in the past, could someone explain what it means.

```
def del_add_cols(df, cols_and_prefs, cols_list):
    temp_df = df.copy()
    del_list = [col[0] for col in cols_and_prefs]
    for col in del_list:
        temp_df.drop([col], axis=1, inplace=True)
    for new_col in cols_list:
        temp_df = pd.concat([temp_df, new_col], axis=1)
    return temp_df
```

Comment: Show us what the arguments of the function stand for. I suppose `df` stands for the pandas dataframe of the dataset. `cols_and_prefs` is a double list ? And of what ? And what about `cols_list`

Comment: I think I would have to show you all of the code for it to make sense, was worth a try putting it on

Comment: This is a function which takes a df, a list of columns to be removed (`cols_and_prefs`) and a list of columns that need to be added to the df (`cols_list`). It removes and adds the indicated columns and returns the df.